# Excel Macro to delete rows in a sheet based on a roster in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I import a lot of Raw data into a sheet "data" and I have another sheet called "Roster" (self-explanatory). I would like to Delete all of the rows in "data" that does not contain any of the names in "Roster". The information in Data is Column J and column A in "roster". I am currently using the code below but it takes a long time.

```
Sub roster_cleanup()

    Const sh1Col As String = "J" 
    Const sh2Col As String = "A"

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Data")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Roster")

    r1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, sh1Col).End(xlUp).Row
    r2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, sh2Col).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = r1 To 2 Step -1
        For Each r In ws2.Range(sh2Col & "2:" & sh2Col & r2)
            If ws1.Cells(i, sh1Col).Value = r.Value Then GoTo myNext
        Next r

        ws1.Cells(i, sh1Col).EntireRow.Delete
myNext:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn off screen updating. Code runs faster without screen flicker
Application.Calculation = xlManual  'Turns auto calc to manual
```

at the beginning of your code and :

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic   'turns auto calc back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn on screen updating
```

at the end of your code, just before End Sub.

I tackled this problem in the past by adding a 'cheater column' with a vlookup to a remote closed reference list.  Then I would place an AutoFilter using VBA on the data, deleting only the visible rows using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete` ... then clear the helper lookup column.  Very fast!  Hope this helps and good luck.